It’s the transition that matters
Cole gave a message to Atis.
"It’s just a very long number!" Atis exclaimed, "The number over here to be specific!"
Cole whispers Atis something, but all she caught was something about numeric operations, primes and transitions.
Can you help Atis work out the message?

Here is the number in full:

14772338200392754886051465220163087566852601827058827627359128101037478729461976552845724014163453747535925484731176624876646213976539334830758719035609759521729592443848697929718068265083375397352579173172712841901833152793042604644508754360741839905380780729042437882807775971043771407327849087156276154638896071943947773235653104971551313


Major Hint:

 Atis suddenly remembers Cole also saying “do $\div 103$ or $- 101$ if you can’t”. Very cryptic nevertheless, but could be the key to solving the puzzle!


As per the hint, divide the number by 103 if it's an exact multiple, and otherwise subtract 101. Keep repeating this and after 368 operations, the number becomes 1. The fact that both operations happen fairly often suggests we're on the the right track. If we record divide-by-103 as "1" and subtract 101 as "0", this gives a sequence of 368 bits.
10000100100111101000011000100110111101100010111000000100110011100111011011110110100101100010111010010110110011100111011010000110010011100010111000000100101001101011011010010110010011100000111000000100010011101111011001100110000001001000011000100110011101101010011011100110100001100000010001110110100001100000010010100110011011101000011000010110000001001010011011101010

The length 368 is a multiple of 8, and grouping into chunks of 8 bits (that is, bytes), we find that they all end in 0, suggesting that we're on the right track. Moreover, 00000100 appears often, whereas most others have the form xxxxx110, which suggests that they're ASCII codes but in reverse. Converting to characters gives
!yadot snoitisnart emirp rof adnega na evah eW

which reverses to the message
We have an agenda for prime transitions today!

The reversal here suggests that we were supposed to record the sequence of operations in reverse, as the multiply-by-103 and add-101 steps that Cole used to produce the number. This would remove needing to reverse each ASCII code and the overall message.

Correct! Well done!
